# Verifying a List of List argument in Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Let's say I have a method that takes  `List<List<MyObject>>` as an argument:

```
public void myFunction(List<List<MyObject>> listOfList) {}
```

I know I can use `anyList()` as a matcher e.g.

```
verify(myClass).myFunction(anyList());
```

However, I get an unchecked assignment warning. I cannot use either of these matchers as they produce compile errors:

```
// Fails - Expects just a single-layered List<MyObject>
verify(myClass).myFunction(anyListOf(MyObject.class));

// Fails - "no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to Class<T>"
verify(myClass).myFunction(anyListOf(anyListOf(MyObject.class)));
```

So how would I create a type-safe matcher for an argument of type `List<List<T>>`?

Comment: No, Its not possible as far as I know. This is a generic issue. Mockito gives predefined matchers for many generic types. For example `anyList()`, `anyMap()` or `anyString()`. But not for `List<List>`. hence you cannot get a type safe matcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a type safe matcher using Matchers.any() and qualifying it with the type:

```
Matchers.<List<List<MyObject>>>any()
```

Comment: Interestingly enough in my case it can be shortened down to just `Matchers.any()` as the argument refers to a concrete class. `"This inspection reports all calls to parametrized methods where explicit argument types can be omitted, since they will be unambiguously inferred by compiler. Such usages make code excessive and thus less readable."`